# Reference Objects inside an observable list (sublist?)

Tags: java

Let's say I have a rather large Observable List and I only want to display couple of data extracted from this list in my view.

Is there a very light way (memory speaking, cheapest complexity) to bind just a portion of my list to my view ? IE : N elements.

I don't want to copy the first 100 elements to a brand new ObservableList because it would just recreate new objects and waste memory. I've heard about sublist but I'm not so sure on how to use them.
I'm asking that because the sample ( N elements displayed) would just be there as an example for users.

I thought about filling my view as I was filling my list but I'd rather keep those parts separated.

```
private ObservableList<?> mixedList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private TableView<?> mixedTable;
mixedTable.setItems(N elements of mixedList);
```

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for [`subList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-)?

Comment: Silly me on the sublist part, I'm really tired out. However my question lies more on what would be the best way to save memory. Is there better than sublist for my problem  ? Especially since I'll have to recast the whole list returned by sublist as an Observable List

Comment: Unfortunately, based on your little example code snippet, using `subList` won't work for you. The `ObservableList` interface doesn't override the method so it's only guaranteed to return a `List`. On top of that, the implementations _don't_ return an instance of `ObservableList` so you can't even "rely" on implementation details (not that you should ever rely on such details).

Comment: Yea I kinda saw that, it didn't display anything at all when I switched to sublist. Do you have any other clue other than sublist ?

Comment: "because it would just recreate new objects". Are you sure about that? I'm suspicious of that statement because my expectation is that it will copy some references.